# How do I calculate current CPU consumption of Processes in Linux (To get value as from TOP command) from /PROC/

Tags: linux, bash, top, cpu-usage

I have a problem with calculating process CPU load in Linux. I have a bash script which is getting all the information about Linux processes from /PROC/PID/STAT during time period of 30s. I am also getting thinks like CLK_TCK, number of CPUs, system uptime and others from /PROC/

```
#!/bin/bash

log_file=/tmp/cpu_last.log
n=1
SYSTEM_UPTIME_SEC=$(tr . ' ' </proc/uptime | awk '{print $1}')
CLK_TCK=$(getconf CLK_TCK)
num_cpus=$(nproc)

while [ $n -le 30 ]
do
    now=$(date +%s%3N)
    SYSTEM_UPTIME_SEC=$(tr . ' ' </proc/uptime | awk '{print $1}')
    echo "$n"
    echo "|$n|$CLK_TCK|$SYSTEM_UPTIME_SEC|$now|$num_cpus|" >> $log_file
    cat /proc/[0-9]*/stat >> $log_file &
    sleep 1
    n=$(( n+1 ))
done]*/stat >> $log_file &
    sleep 1
done
```

My goal is calculate from those data current CPU consumption by specific processes. I tried multiple formulas (utime + stime from first period of data collecting - utime + stime from second period / clk / seconds etc) but i never got same value that I can see in TOP command. So, can you help me to get right formula for calculating how much CPU% process currently consuming?

I tired different formulas to calculate current CPU load for processes, but I am still getting different results against TOP results. I want to calculate current CPU consumption by process, but none of my formulas work. I need to use data from /PROC/ to collect data, because I am working on low HW linux system and my data collecting must have as low impact on system as possible.

Comment: I think this https://github.com/sysstat/sysstat (pidstat) much better than a bash script. Check it.

Comment: @K-att- Probably it would, but as I mentioned this is low HW system and I am unable to install any apps on in, in the other words I have to use what system already offer and while doing that I have to minimize impact on system resources.

Comment: That's why I advised the pidstat. It is written in C.

Comment: @JakubHořínek depending on your machine, the `pidstat` binary that you could just compile on a different machine for your target machine. If you can copy over a shell script, you can also copy over that. Not saying that because of that, a shell script approach is invalid, just saying that "I have little resources on the target machine" is really no argument; the whole binary typically runs at less than 64 kB, and links only to your systems libc (which is there, anyways)

Comment: @MarcusMüller Ohh... In that case it would be perfect. I tried pidstat on different Linux and it´s working perfectly for my cause.
Unfortunately on device I need to log, it is not available.
If you saying that I can compile pidstat push it to the device collect data and dele it it would be perfect, but how do I do that?? I am sorry for stupid question, but I am kinda beginner in Linux systems.

Comment: not a stupid question at all! But I don't know what your target platform is, so it's going to be hard to answer in brief. Can you post a new question where you say what your target is, and what the machine is that you would want to use to compile? Say you want to *cross-compile* the sysstat utilities (esp. pidstat) from the link above.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I compile pidstat on my kali-linux and test in on the Kali-linux. It worked. But the target system is some kind of Yocto-standard GNU/Linux and on that it doesn´t wok. I am getting this message after launching ./pidstat: "/tmp/pidstat: line 1: syntax error: unexpected "("
Should I compile it on different Linux? Or should I try different version of Pidstat??

Comment: if this target is yocto, it probably gives you an SDK with which you have to compile for the target. (building software for an embedded target in a reliable way is exactly the point of yocto)

Comment: @MarcusMüller So I have to get SDK from the developer of this system to be able to compile pidstat for it??
I won´t be able to somehow compile it on my own?

Comment: it should be no problem, but the whole point of the SDK is making it *easier*. In this case, you seem to have not used the right compiler. I don't know your target architecture, so I can't advise.

Comment: @MarcusMüller HW architecture is aarch64. Do I need some more info?

Comment: did you use an aarch64-linux targeting compiler?

Comment: I used "make" command on my virtual Kali linux system. Honestly, I don´t know any other method / right method to compile it. Maybe you can help me.

Comment: that won't work. you need to tell configure to use the right compiler. Run `./configure --help` to see what you need to do. Essentially, all you need to do is install a compatible aarch64-targetting C compiler (and binutils), and specify `CC` and `LD`. As said above, a very easy way of doing so is using the SDK for your platform.